# Webpack - import const from .d.ts file not working - Can't resolve '@nuvolo/servicenow-types/server/GlideRecord'

Tags: javascript, webpack, servicenow

I'm doing this:

`import { GlideRecord } from "@nuvolo/servicenow-types/server/GlideRecord";`

I have a file `node_modules/@nuvolo/servicenow-types/server/GlideRecord.d.ts`

It contains:

```
...
type GlideRecordConstructor = { new <T>(table: string): GlideRecord<T> };
type GlideRecord<T> = GlideRecordBase<T> & T;
declare const GlideRecord: GlideRecordConstructor;
export { GlideRecord };
```

If I run `tsc` it works, no errors

Webpack says:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@nuvolo/servicenow-types/server/GlideRecord' in ...

Webpack config:

```
    {
                mode: "production",
                //set name of record as the library name
                output: {
                    filename: "file.js"
                },
                module: {
                    rules: [
                        {
                            test: /\.ts$/,
                            use: 'ts-loader',
                            //use: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
                            exclude: /node_modules/,
                        },
                    ],
                },
                resolve: {
                    //modules: ['node_modules'],
                    extensions: [ '.ts', '.js' ], // Allows imports to work from .ts and .js
                },
            }
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "transpile": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true
  }
}
```

how do I fix this?

I've also created a GH issue here: https://github.com/nuvolo/sincronia/issues/138

Comment: Does it work if you use the full path?

Comment: Full path makes no difference

Comment: Do you currently have `node_modules/@nuvolo/servicenow-types/server/GlideRecord.js` file over there?

Comment: @tmhao2005 No - I have GlideRecord.d.ts only - the implementation is provided by the framework that the script runs in - I only have the type definitions - if I `import type` it complains that I'm using the type as an object when I do `new GlideRecord<any>()`

Comment: Why don't you reference to it by using triple splash directive `///` or trying to add to `files` list in your `tsconfig.json`

Comment: Which /// directive would I use - https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html